# Как получить скриншот с vkontakte

Tags: видео, vkontakte-api

есть видео с vk 
 <iframe src="http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=25171954&id=168755720&hash=5313f6f507bcf7ff&hd=1" width="607" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>

не пойму как мне получить скриншот с него.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [`video.get()`](https://vk.com/dev/video.get) возвращает информацию о видео, включая адрес картинки. В вашем случае id видео получается совмещением через знак подчеркивания `oid` и `id`:  `25171954_168755720`

Вот как выглядит ответ API:
[image: скриншот]

Comment: каким метотодом передавать значение в скрипт передаеться post а как то можно get

Comment: Можно [и *POST* и *GET*](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests).

Comment: покажите тогда полный урл get не могу разобраться извините

Comment: Как-то так:

    https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?videos=25171954_168755720&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_ВАШЕГО_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ

Comment: вот с этим и проблема access_token=  как его получить не пойму

Comment: Прочитать [документацию](https://vk.com/dev), [создать приложение](https://vk.com/editapp?act=create), получить токен. Там есть варианте - от чьего имени будет обращаться к API скрипт: вашего сайта, пользователя зашедшего туда, или вас лично.

Comment: не пашет оно не фига... я не знаю для кого писали эту документацию но я не чего не понимаю, я Вас добавил в скайп можете подтвердить?

Comment: Разбирайтесь с документацией. Иначе никак.